# ChartJS 3 doesn't display legend

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using ChartJS 3.7 and even when I pass `options.plugins.legend.display` a `true`, the legend isn't displayed. How do I get the legend to show?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ChartsJS Legend not showing in Angular11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67949447/chartsjs-legend-not-showing-in-angular11)

Comment: @LeeLenalee I'm not using Angular.

Comment: No but it&#39;s litterly the same problem with the same solution

Comment: @LeeLenalee No, the problem is different because the reproduction case is different. The solution is the same.
ChartJS documentation is currently unclear about registration of legend.

Comment: Alright Lemmy clarify it other way, underlying problem is the same, also chart.js is open source so you are welcome to improve it

Answer (score 1):

Looks like newer versions of ChartJS require you to register the individual elements you're going to use.
You need to register the legend specifically.

```js
import { Chart, Legend } from 'chart.js';
// ...
Chart.register(Legend);
```